# PHP includes, htaccess, and allow_url_fopen

Tags: php, .htaccess, include-path

Scenario: Developing on hosted server, htaccess = Basic Auth, allow_url_fopen = on

Problem: When I include files with their url location, my htaccess blocks the include and returns a 401 error.

Known solutions: relative path (../), $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Question: Is there another way?  I'd like to keep the url, if possible, in this scenario.  Also, I'm using an include file for my footers, should I use tpl instead (I know nothing about tpl)?

EDIT:  I'm currently making a mess of my folder structure.  I have example.com and secure.example.com (where the ssl is installed).  So in my secure folder I want to include files from the root.  I thought it might be easier if I used the URL because the 'document_root' call only takes me to the secure folder (not root), and if I move a file the relative path may not work.

Comment: This should happen only if you request a local resource via http://. Can you show an example?

Comment: Why do you want to keep it an URL include?

Comment: Good question.  I'll make an edit above giving more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to do this. That's the reason the option is turned off by default. A better way of handling this is to grab the files from with `libcurl`.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Then you can write the data to a file and include it. This is still a really risky behavior, though, because you're trusting a remote source. A chain is only as secure as its weakest link. Using SSH and periodically syncing might be a viable alternative.